# angular changing the url location without reloading the page

Tags: angularjs

I have some partials which are loaded with some URL `templates/test.html` for example. This `TemplateURL` will always be relative. I want to use the same templates in different locations within the website.

So , I want to use the same relative url `http://somedomain.com/templates/Test.html` even if I am on some actual url of `http://somedaomian.com/some1/some2`

I have tried to use the `$loaction` service, but I am unable to set the $loaction back to the `home` url when I need to.

E.g in my controller I would like to :

```
var new_base_url = homeURL();

function homeUrl() {
   /* Here is where I am unable to get the home url */
   $location.path('/');      // simply returns the current url 

};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the absolute Url, `$location.absUrl()` will return everything (all url segments).

If you want the host name, `$location.host()` will return the host name.

If you want the protocol, `$location.protocol()` will return that.

If you want the path, `$location.path()` will return that.

If you want the hash, `$location.hash()` will return that.

You should be able to use these methods to parse out the pieces of the url that you are after.

```
var path = $location.path();
var hash = $location.hash();
var basePath = path.replace(hash, '');
```

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping for a lazy way ... for some reason, `$loaction.path()` return nothing even if there is a `/something/something`